# C# Dictionary of classes with generic type

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming, generic-list

I'm trying to create a Genetic algorithm in C# but I want to separate the genes into classes (chromosomes)

basically I have a DNA class that is defined as

```
public class DNA<T> { public T[] Genes { get; private set; } }
```

so I can have genes of type double, bool, int and etc...

Then I want to define a chromosome as

```
class Chromosome
{
    Dictionary<string, DNA<T>> chromosomes;
}
```

So I would be able to add to the chromosome multiple DNA types like

```
chromosomes.add("brain", new DNA<double>(...));
chromosomes.add("traits", new DNA<bool>(...));
chromosomes.add("body", new DNA<int>(...));
```

Should the dictionary value be `object` or sould I create an `IDNA` Interface to the DNA class to hold the object then cast it everytime I need? Or there is an easier/best way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: You should make `Chromosome` class generic, otherwise `Dictionary<string, DNA<T>> chromosomes;` will not compile

Comment: I first tought about that, but then it would render the Chromosome class accepting only one type of gene (eg. int only)
I want it to accept multiple kinds of genes

Comment: Your dictionary would have to be declared taking a type that is common between those subtypes, either a base class or an interface, that `DNA<T>` inherits from/implements.

Comment: @feehmt: As a total aside, you may consider using a `KeyedCollection` here instead of a `Dictionary`. That way, you can add the name of the phenotype to your `DNA<T>` class, while still being able to do lookups by that key name. That might make the code a bit simpler and intuitive since your key will be associated with the underlying value object, and thus always accessible whenever you have a reference to that object.

Comment: @feehmt: Also unrelated to your question—and acknowledging that this may be a simplified example for the sake of illustrating your problem: Most phenotypes derive from the expression of genes across multiple chromosomes, as I'm sure you know. As such, categorizing your `DNA<T>` by chromosome may not be the most effective way of modeling many phenotypes (assuming that's what the `DNA<T>` class is intended to represent the collection of genes associated with a particular phenotypic trait).

Answer (score 2):

For multiple kind of genes as you wrote you could use interface/abstract class.

For data access instead of casting you can write a simple method `GetDNAOfType`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Chromosome
{
   Dictionary<string, DNA> chromosomes = new Dictionary<string, DNA>();

   public IEnumerable<DNA<T>> GetDNAOfType<T>()
   {
      return chromosomes.Values.OfType<DNA<T>>();
   }

   public void AddDNA(string key, DNA dna)
   {
      if (chromosomes.ContainsKey(key))
         chromosomes[key] = dna;
      else
         chromosomes.Add(key, dna);
   }
}
```

```
public abstract class DNA
{
}

public class DNA<T> : DNA
{
   public T[] Genes { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I think it will work for what I need
Thanks! :)